# Validating a string with comma-separated alphanumeric words only OR just spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a regex that allows alphanumeric characters separated by comma. Or just spaces. Without a comma as the first character.

**What I am trying to do:**

- "101010101sadadsasd,120120310231023a,adasdads1231,asdasdasda1231"
- "                         " < -- case of just spaces of any number

**What I am trying to avoid:**

- "&*#@*@$,asdasdads,asdsd@!@"
- ",aasdas,asdasd"
- "  asda asdsad asdasd ,asdasd"

What's acceptable but not wanted: (can live with it)

- ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
- "asdasdasdas,asdasd123123,adsasd23123," <-- I can just trim(",")

Below is screenshot of the implementation and the event where isMatch = true even though the value is symbols and not alphanumeric.

The link shows a screenshot of the problem, and the screenshot code is as follows:

```cs
bool result = true;
Regex regx = new Regex(@"(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9,-,]*$| *)");
if (regx.IsMatch(rowUpdate.ConNoteNumber))
{
    result = false;
}
return result;
```

Comment: Ah, you mean you have comma-separated alphanumerics? So, try `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*|\s*)$`

Comment: I did add an image @Luuk. It's in the link at the bottom of my post?

Comment: `^(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9,]*)|\s+)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*|\s*)$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:`

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - one or more letters/digits, and then zero or more occurrences of a comma and one or more letters/digits
- `|` - or

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of string (if the regex is executed on the server side, `$` can be replaced with `\z`, too).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YB0MOn/1).

Comment: I since implemented this and it works perfectly. Thank you for your time Wiktor.